# Codewarrior doesn't accept __COUNTER__ macro although it exists in the compiler reference

Tags: c++, windows, macros, counter, codewarrior

I read in the *CodeWarrior Build Tools Reference for Power Architecture* that the __COUNTER__ predefined macro exists for Codewarrior like for MSVC or GCC. But, when I try to build my project I get :

```
Error   : undefined identifier '__COUNTER__'
```

Does anyone know if it is a recent integration to codewarrior or if there is an option to activate it ? Or even if it's included only in some specific versions of the codewarrior compilers ? (I use the CW Power Architecture 8.8 build 80229).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. For the ones who get that problem, you need to download and install the last codewarrior update one the freescale website (it was the 8.8.5 when I wrote this question).